# Cannot run mlflow in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, mlflow

I'm trying to run mlflow on Rstudio on win system. I install mlflow package using this command `install.packages("mlflow")`. And then I run the following code,

```
library(mlflow)

mlflow_ui()
```

This error is reported:

```
Error in wait_for(function() mlflow_rest("experiments", "search", client = client,  : 
  Operation failed after waiting for 10 seconds
```

I tried a few other command, like `mlflow_log_metric("foo", 1)`. it's still the same error. I'm new to this package. Is there any way to fix this error? Thanks.

Comment: `traceback()` might give useful information. You might also check where you have all the packages dependencies.

Comment: @IRTFM I run traceback(), below is what returned. Cannot find where is the issue from.

6: stop("Operation failed after waiting for ", wait, " seconds")
5: wait_for(function() mlflow_rest("experiments", "search", client = client, 
       verb = "POST", data = list(max_results = 1)), getOption("mlflow.connect.wait", 
       10), getOption("mlflow.connect.sleep", 1))
4: mlflow_validate_server(client)
3: mlflow_client()
2: mlflow_ui.NULL()
1: mlflow_ui()

I install all packages using the same command. Can you hint more on "where are packages dependencies"? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like there’s an attempt to access some via a POST operation and it’s failing. You should try to understand the package’s external (web) dependencies.

Comment: @IRTFM Thank you for your response. I'm new to this type of issue. I searched this manual "mlflow: R interface for MLflow", and followed it. But still cannot work. I searched for POST operations and packages external dependencies, but still cannot figure it out. Could you give a bit more hint on the root cause, or provide some link. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @IRTFM By the way, I installed mlflow python package, and I can run it using spyder or use python to call it inside terminal. However, I cannot run it from rstudio or call it using R from terminal.

Comment: @IRTFM This post gives me some hint. "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60641337/mlflow-r-installation-mlflow-python-bin", it may be because the cluster in rstudio doesn't have outside connective privileges. I followed the method and set MLFLOW_BIN and MLFLOW_PYTHON_BIN with intern =TRUE. But still doesn't work.

Comment: I see you did some searching. I would not limit the search to SO but rather search with google. Alsio use `packageDescription("mlflow")` to see what "BugReports:"  destination is recommended. When communicating with the `mlflow`-people you do a much better job of describing the entire process and your system setup. I cannot tell what system you are on and that is surely essential info.

Comment: @IRTFM Thank you for all the info. Super helpful!